# How to return IEnumerable<T> from web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, generics, c#-4.0

I was wondering why I can't return an `IEnumerable<T>` through a web service.

In my webservice I return an `IEnumerable<T>` but when I check the IntelliSense in VS 2010 I see it's giving me a `T[]`.

Can someone give me an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Are you asking about an ASMX web service, or WCF? The answers are different between the two.

Answer (score 8):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479866.aspx):

**Can I Use Generics in Web Services?**

Unfortunately, no. Web services have to expose a WSDL-based contract. Such contracts are always limited by the expressiveness of the message format being used. For example, HTTP-GET based web services only support primitive types such as int or string, but not complex types like a DataSet. SOAP-based web services are more capable, but SOAP has no ability to represent generic type parameters. As a result, at present, you cannot define web services that rely on generic types. That said, you can define .NET web services that rely on closed constructed generic types, for example:

```
public class MyWebService 
{
   [WebMethod]
   public List<string> GetCities() 
   {
      List<string> cities = new List<string>();
      cities.Add("New York");
      cities.Add("San Francisco");
      cities.Add("London");
      return cities;
   }
}
```

In the above example, List will be marshaled as an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Array `T[]` supports `IEnumerable<T>`

You **are** returning `IEnumerable<T>`

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Something()
    {
        return new T[] {};
    }
```